# What does int a mean

Tags: c++, declaration, definition

As specified into the standard `int a` belongs to the simple `declaration`. Actually

```
simple-declaration:
    decl-specifier-seq_opt init-declarator-list_opt ; //
    attribute-specifier-seq decl-specifier-seq_opt init-declarator-list ;
type-specifier:
    trailing-type-specifier //
    class-specifier
    enum-specifier
trailing-type-specifier:
    simple-type-specifier //
    elaborated-type-specifier
    typename-specifier
    cv-qualifier
simple-type-specifier:
    nested-name-specifieropt type-name
    nested-name-specifier template simple-template-id
    char
    char16_t
    char32_t
    wchar_t
    bool
    short
    int //
    long
    signed
    unsigned
    float
    double
    void
    auto
    decltype-specifier
```

Hence `int a` is a simple declaration. But if we redeclare `a` into the same scope as the following:

```
int a;
int a;
```

We have

```
test.cpp:4:5: error: redefinition of ‘int a’
test.cpp:3:5: error: ‘int a’ previously declared here
```

So what exactly `int a` is?

Comment: What part of the standard says that you are allowed to perform two declarations of the same variable in the same scope?

Comment: @merlin2011 I think the question is, what makes `int a;` a *definition* in this context. It has to be a *definition* to break the ODR rule.

Comment: @user2357112 I don't understand, does ODR applied in this case?

Comment: Its a simple programming logic if you want to store integer value you have to declare a variable to create a memory location for this. now the location is identified by variable "a". So now you are not able to declare the same variable for new int memory location.

Comment: @JitendraPareek I don't interested in programming in this question. I want to find formal rules into the standard.

Comment: See also:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration

Answer (score 9):

They are each syntactically valid declarations, however the two together violate of the [one definition rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule). The compiler detects and reports this violation. (They are both declarations and definitions.)

Comment: ODR applies to definition, not declaration

Comment: These are both both declarations and definitions. (Answer updated)

Comment: Can you get a reference to the part of standard said that int a is definition?

Comment: @Dmitrii see Rakibul Hasan's answer.

Comment: See 3.1 which defines what "declarations" and "definitions" are. It even gives `int a;` as an example of a definition and `extern int a;` as an example of a declaration that is not a definition.

Comment: Thanks, I've found it. But what's the definition of definition? I can't find it in the standard. Only examples of definition and definiton of declaration which refers to the definition.

Comment: Just go back a bit. The beginning of 3.1 has it.

Comment: Are you use N3797 working draft? Because I can't find this definition into the 3.1. Can you give a quote?

Answer (score 6):

From the standard

```
A declaration is a definition unless it declares a function without specifying the function’s body
```

`a` is not a method, so `int a` means a declaration and definition. And if you define a name more than once in a single translation unit, you are violating [One definition Rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule), hence the error.

**EDIT**

For clarification, I am posting the whole paragraph:

> A declaration is a definition unless it declares a function without
>   specifying the function’s body   (8.4), it contains the extern
>   specifier (7.1.1) or a linkage-specification (27) (7.5) and neither an
>   initializer nor a function-body, it declares a static data member in a
>   class definition (9.4), it is a  class name declaration (9.1), or it
>   is a typedef declaration (7.1.3),a using-declaration (7.3.3), or a 
>   using-directive(7.3.4).

Comment: Are you sure that is the relevant part of the standard? I would have expected something about types too (`struct Foo;` is a declaration and not a definition)?

Comment: @juanchopanza all that matters here: `int a` is a definition, so the ODR applies. +1 for the best answer.

Comment: @juanchopanza this is just a beginning of a paragraph, there is a whole bunch of other stuff in that "unless" clause.

Comment: @FerdinandBeyer Well, in isolation the quote is actually wrong, which is why I was asking.

Answer (score 0):

It is same as two persons having same name. the compiler confuses which one to refer. So, it is not allowed in same scope. Having two variables with same name is confusing for the compiler.

Comment: The counter example is the redeclaration as extern int a; extern int a;

Answer (score 0):

we use **declarations** to **declare variable names and types** as well as **to define memory for them**. Most of the time these two actions occur at the same time, that is, **most declarations are definitions** (In case of variables and not functions). Hence the error. However this may not always be a case.